# Windows user logintime

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We have two windows forests with a one-direction trust. 
I noticed, that a password/group-membership change informs the other DC just in time. 
This also happens, when I create a new user in forest A for accessing on a DB in forest B.
 Normally it takes about 30 minutes for forest A and B for balancing their database.
Why does this happen just in time?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "just in time". I also don't understand what you mean by "balancing their database". There's no AD database "balancing" or merging" in a DomainTrust.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that in an AD Trust, objects don't replicate from one forest to the other.  A request for an AD object is fulfilled through the trusted forest.  This means that a change in Forest A doesn't have to replicate to Forest B.  If a user in Forest A tries to log into an account in Forest B, they would be authenticating to Forest B's DCs through the trust.

That being stated, here's some background on replication.

Certain AD items are flagged as "Urgent Replication" and replicate immediately [How the Active Directory Replication Model Works - Urgent Replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772726%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#w2k3tr_repup_how_huzs).

Password changes are replicated differently than normal and urgent and are directly replicated to the PDC emulator role DC.  This results in logging in with a new password not causing an error if the DC hasn't received the new replicated password.

Groups are now (2003 AD and newer) replicated with attribute deltas rather than full attribute replication.  This is called linked-value replication and results in much better handling of group membership lists.

Answer (score -1):

I think everything looks normal here it's definitely normal to sync at the same moment unless there's something making it take up to 30 minutes other than that you shouldn't be worried you should be happy .